# How to create vignette type effect like Netflix' navigation bar using HTML, CSS

Tags: html, css, navigationbar

I'm creating a website, which like Netflix has a video playing on the background, and the navigation bar is transparent, however I want it to be like Netflix' navigation bar having a vignette type effect from the top.
[image]

Also, please suggest if there is a more effective method than using the vignette effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sahil.

The most efficient way I can think to achieve this would be to set the background of your navbar to be a gradient.

You can make the gradient go from a slightly transparent black to totally transparent and that should create a vignette-style effect.

Try and apply the following style to your navbar (remove any other background styling):

```
background: rgb(0,0,0);
background: linear-gradient(180deg, rgba(0,0,0,0.6629026610644257) 0%, rgba(9,9,121,0) 57%);
```

If you wish to modify the transparency or colours, you can use [CSSGradient](https://cssgradient.io/) to make gradients. Just make sure to set the angle to be 180deg and you should be good!

Hope this helped!